# Netezza Groom table is not removing deleted records

Tags: sql, netezza

Below is the tested SQL code in Aginity that i have tried to track how grooming table works but i have checked it several times and to my surprise deleted records does exists in the table. Is there any time frame for them to be removed?

```
--1382159 records

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AS_TEST_WORK;

--1111 records deleted

DELETE FROM AS_TEST_WORK WHERE rrn_num LIKE '324%'; 

--setting deleted records for a display

SET show_deleted_records = true;  

--So i can see the deleted records

SELECT createxid, deletexid, COUNT(*) from AS_TEST_WORK GROUP BY 1, 2 ORDER BY 1;

--Groom table command to remove the deleted records permanently

GROOM TABLE as_test_work records all;  

--Re confirming by setting for a display

SET show_deleted_records = true; 

--To my surprise i can still see the deleted records

SELECT createxid, deletexid, COUNT(*) from AS_TEST_WORK GROUP BY 1, 2 ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

> GROOM TABLE AS_TEST_WORK RECLAIM BACKUPSET NONE;

By default, groom only removes records if they've been backed up. This is documented [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.adm.doc/c_sysadm_grooming_tables.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but still it didn't work and i am getting following output when running this command that nothing has been removed:  "NOTICE:  Groom processed 1200 pages; purged 0 records; scan size unchanged; table size unchanged."

Comment: That's odd, it works for me (version 7.0, default configuration). Are you sure the table had logically deleted rows before the groom statement? There may be a configuration parameter that disables this behavior but it would surely not be the default.

Comment: Could you please let me know the parameter name so that i can check because the deleted records got purged after backup with the same statement of RECLAIM BACKUPSET NONE. I am also using version 7.0, striper architecture.